# C++ range based for loop gives SIGABRT while normal loop works fine

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, for-loop

This code works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
    painter.drawRect(grid[i].rect);
```

This code does not work:

```
for (Square square : grid)
    painter.drawRect(square.rect);
```

It fails at runtime printing:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc The program has unexpectedly finished.

This is the call stack:

```
1  raise
0x7ffff53cf91f 
2  abort
0x7ffff53d151a 
3  __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()
0x7ffff5f3f52d 
4  ??
0x7ffff5f3d2d6 
5  std::terminate()
0x7ffff5f3d321 
6  __cxa_throw
0x7ffff5f3d539 
7  operator new(unsigned long)
0x7ffff5f3dafc 
8  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Square>::allocate
new_allocator.h 104 0x408548       
9  std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Square>>::allocate
alloc_traits.h  416 0x408308       
10 std::_Vector_base<Square, std::allocator<Square>>::_M_allocate
stl_vector.h    170 0x407f54       
11 std::_Vector_base<Square, std::allocator<Square>>::_M_create_storage
stl_vector.h    185 0x407b99       
12 std::_Vector_base<Square, std::allocator<Square>>::_Vector_base stl_vector.h    136 0x4078f3       
13 std::vector<Square>::vector
stl_vector.h    322 0x4075c3       
14 Square::Square
square.h        19  0x407406       
15 Canvas::Canvas
canvas.cpp      23  0x406752       
16 MainWindow::MainWindow
mainwindow.cpp  10  0x4044b6
main.cpp        7   0x404310
```

The problem happens at `canvas.cpp`

Kindly shed some light as to what might be the causing this issue.

Comment: The range-based loop makes a copy of every element, while the index-based loop doesn't. It appears that `Square` is expensive to copy. Make it `for (Square& square : grid) {...}` (note the ampersand).

Comment: You're right! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two loops you are trying are not equivalent at all. The first one uses `grid[i]`, the `[]` operator of `vector` returns a `reference` to the element in the vector, not a copy of it. The second version uses the based-range for: but the way you wrote it, `for(Square square : grid`, you ask it to make a `copy` of each element and place it in the variable `square`.

It appears that your `Square` object is a heavy object or has some problems with its copy constructor, leading to the `bad_alloc`. However, since the first version works well, to do the equivalent you need to make the range-based-for work on a reference, not a copy of each element:

```
for (Square& square : grid)  // <-- return a reference on each element.
    painter.drawRect(square.rect);
```

Even preferably return a `const ref` whenever it is enough for the required action on the element:

```
for (const Square& square : grid) // <-- return a const ref whenever it is enough and the subsequent action does not modify the object
    painter.drawRect(square.rect);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Square is heavy indeed. It is time to use pointers because the stack isn't gonna behave well any longer.

Comment: It doesn't appear that any of your `Square`s are on the stack. They are all stored in `std::vector<Square>`, and vector places its actual contents on the heap.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I guess your comment is directed to the OP's comment, and it is true. Adam it is not a matter of stack here, but anyway, using the reference will solve the issue. Glad it helped.